# .NET core 1.0 connection to MySQL on a Linux

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linux

Does anybody know if it is possible to connect to a MySQL database with a Linux distribution of ASP.NET Core 1.0, or does it only support Entity Framework and MSSQL?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search yielded the following result:
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector

Looking at the tests, here's an example connection and query:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"select 1;";
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            Assert.Equal(true, await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have seen it. But it looks like it is missing a lot of thinks. But thanks for the input

Comment: @Sjuften: I'm the author of MySqlConnector. What are the primary features you'd like to see supported in this project for it to meet your needs?

Comment: Hey Bradley.  Im am missing some data types,  for fully selling the solution for my boss. By the way,  you have a done a really,  really great work. And,  for my own projects o am using your solution.  So thank you,  for the great effort and i hope you keep beeing awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql-connector-net-netstandard](https://github.com/SapientGuardian/mysql-connector-net-netstandard).

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // execute query or command
}
```

ASP.NET Core supports any other ORM which work on .NET Core.
You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). 
It's great fast micro ORM.
Dapper uses IDbConnection.

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}  

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
}
```